# BDL primary driver inner plate install

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, harley-davidson

I am for the first time ever, in the process of installing a replacement Ultima 6 speed transmission with the same make and model on my 1994 Harley Davidson softail custom trike conversion. It has a 113 CI Ultima motor and a BDL primary belt drive.  I have the new transmission in place and when I try to install the inner primary plate it bolts to the transmission but is off alignment by almost a quarter inch on the motor side. I tried loosing the bolts on the transmission so it can move and it still won’t line up. I am looking for any suggestions you can provide. I really want to get back out on the road.

Comment: Is there any way to get some pictures, especially of the two different transmissions and mounting positions, etc. That it is a custom does not give us a *lot* of information to go on. I can visually see what you are asking, but need some frame of reference to see where you may be going wrong.